# JQuery accordion: reverting back to previous style for “closed” state

Tags: jquery, html, accordion, sliding

I'm using a simple JQuery accordion that uses DIV's rather than the typical UL structure.

- When you click on a *menu* DIV, a specific corresponding *panel* DIV slides open.
- The *menu* DIV's style changes (goes grey) to show that it's active.
- When you click on it again, the *panel* DIV closes.
- **When this happens I want the *menu* DIV to revert back to it's previous style.**
- At the moment it just stays grey.

Can anyone help?

Here is the code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gaelen/aTR2b/6/

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu1").data("panelId", "#collapse_photography");
    $("#menu2").data("panelId", "#collapse_fineart");
    $("#menu3").data("panelId", "#collapse_architecture");
    $("#menu4").data("panelId", "#collapse_graphdesign");
    $("#menu5").data("panelId", "#collapse_infographics");
    $("#menu6").data("panelId", "#collapse_3dviz");

    $("#menu1, #menu2, #menu3, #menu4, #menu5, #menu6").click(function() {
        $(".menu_active").removeClass('menu_active');
        $(this).addClass('menu_active');
        var first = true;
        var panelId = $(this).data("panelId");
        $(".class1").not(panelId).slideUp(function() {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
                $(panelId).slideToggle(400);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.class1 {width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid black; display:none;}
.menu_active{ background: grey;}
#collapse_photography {background:red; margin-bottom:10px;}
#collapse_fineart {background:red; margin-bottom:10px;}
#collapse_architecture {background:red; margin-bottom:10px;}
#collapse_graphdesign {background:red; margin-bottom:10px;}
#collapse_infographics {background:red; margin-bottom:10px;}
#collapse_3dviz {background:red; margin-bottom:10px;}
#menu1 {cursor:pointer; display:block; width:200px; border:1px solid black; margin-bottom:10px;}
#menu2 {cursor:pointer; display:block; width:200px; border:1px solid black; margin-bottom:10px;}
#menu3 {cursor:pointer; display:block; width:200px; border:1px solid black; margin-bottom:10px;}
#menu4 {cursor:pointer; display:block; width:200px; border:1px solid black; margin-bottom:10px;}
#menu5 {cursor:pointer; display:block; width:200px; border:1px solid black; margin-bottom:10px;}
#menu6 {cursor:pointer; display:block; width:200px; border:1px solid black; margin-bottom:10px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu1"><a href="#">Photography</a></div>
<div id="collapse_photography" class="class1">Content 1</div>
<div id="menu2">Fine Art</div>
<div id="collapse_fineart" class="class1">Content 2</div>
<div id="menu3">Architecture</div>
<div id="collapse_architecture" class="class1">Content 3</div>
<div id="menu4">Graphic + Web Design</div>
<div id="collapse_graphdesign" class="class1">Content 4</div>
<div id="menu5">Information Graphics</div>
<div id="collapse_infographics" class="class1">Content 5</div>
<div id="menu6">3D Visualisation</div>
<div id="collapse_3dviz" class="class1">Content 6</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
    $(".menu_active").not(this).removeClass('menu_active');
    $(this).toggleClass('menu_active');
```

**Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/aTR2b/8/).**